# Asset is not precompiled in RoR Openshift app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, production-environment, openshift

I have a Ruby on Rails OpenShift application (ruby 1.9, Rails Rails 3.2.13), working without problems in development environment. However, when I deploy the application to OpenShift, I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (logo.png isn't precompiled):
    2:   <header>
    3:     <div id="header" class="clearfix landing_header">
    4:       <a href="#" id="logo">
    5:         <%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
    6: 
    7:       </a>
```

I understand that the error says logo.png is not precompiled. That would make sense since those directives are set in my `production.rb` environment:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

Well, are my assets precompiled? When I deploy my app (using `git push`), I can see among others:

```
remote: Precompiling with 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile'
```

And no error... Even if I search for the precompiled assets in the OpenShift repo using SSH, I can see it there, again with many others:

```
> ls public/assets | grep logo
logo-66589ea9e7a1caa7f2151a721d6cdbd2.png
```

When I hit my app address/assets/that file ^^ in the browser, I can see it. The only problem is that image_tag does not.

What am I doing wrong? The assets are precompiled, aren't they? Am I using image_tag incorrectly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like it is related to this issue: https://github.com/openshift/origin-community-cartridges/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

precompile assets on your local system and then push the code. surely it will work.

Comment: Maybe it will, but... Isn't OpenShift supposed to precompile assets for me? Anyway, the precompiled assets files ARE in the desired location, only the Rails app does not say so.

Comment: Well, but what's the problem then? Bug in OpenShift?

Answer (score 0):

Little late to answer, but I ran into some issues with this as well and this is how I solved it.  When I do a 'git push' to oepnshift it does precompile the assets as seen in the console

```
remote: Precompiling with 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile'
```

Problem i believe this is pre-compiling using my development settings, not production ones.  To fix this I added a a few lines in the deploy action hook file (app -> .openshift -> action_hooks - deploy)

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

This forces it to use the production config file for precompiling.

The only problem is now when I do a git push, it precompiles twice, once is the out-of-the-box by openshift, and the second in the action hooks.  Still should work though.